# Add a line break in a function's definition for the return type

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there some way to add a line break for the return type in a function definition, without using a backslash?

What I don't want:

```
def line_intersection(a : Vector, b : Vector, c : Vector, d : Vector) \
                                -> Vector | None | Tuple[Vector, Vector]:
```

What I do want (but this does not work):

```
def line_intersection(a : Vector, b : Vector, c : Vector, d : Vector)
                                -> Vector | None | Tuple[Vector, Vector]:
```

Comment: Breaking the line before the ) should work. Not sure for after the ->. What happens if you throw it into an automatic code formatter?

Comment: Also I think you get the syntax wrong -- [PEP 604 -- Allow writing union types as X | Y | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0604/)

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: Are you asking for a nicer way or a way that works? Your question is currently a little unclear in that regard?

Comment: Closing this question as "opinion based" is dishonest to say the least.

Answer (score -1):

If you're trying use type annotations in function signature, then you need to use `Union` instead of `or`.

A quick explanation on this:

- **Union:** Emulates the OR operation.
- **Optional**: Emulates the `or None` operation.

**Code:**

```py
from typing import Optional, Tuple, Union


def line_intersection(
        a: Vector,
        b: Vector,
        c: Vector,
        d: Vector) -> Optional[Union[Vector, Tuple[Vector, Vector]]]:
    pass
```

Comment: This however doesn't answer the question of how to add a line break before the ->